# Listing of files in the directory in apache2 ubuntu

Tags: apache2, installation, localhost, ubuntu-12.04

Hie all, i have installed apache2 server on my ubuntu 12.04 system, now i want that instead of showing its own page on typing  `http://localhost` it should `display the list of files` in the `/var/www` directory which is it's default directory.
please help me to achieve this
thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can remove the file called index.html or set up `Options +Indexes` option in your apache site setting file :)